# Javascript/Jquery : Mathematically Divide Two Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
var frameWidth = 400;
var imageWidth = $('#inner-image').css('width');
var numberOfFrames = imageWidth/frameWidth;
```

How do I make "numberOfFrames" display as a quotient? I.E. process "frameWidth" and "imageWidth" as numbers, rather than objects?

Let me know if I need to explain myself more clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.css('width')` is likely returning the value with `px`. You can use `parseInt()` to get only the number.

```
var frameWidth = 400;
var imageWidth = parseInt( $('#inner-image').css('width'), 10);
var numberOfFrames = imageWidth/frameWidth;
```

The second argument `10` specifies the base that `parseInt()` should use.

You can also use the [`width()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method to get the result without the `px`.

```
var frameWidth = 400;
var imageWidth = +$('#inner-image').width();
var numberOfFrames = imageWidth/frameWidth;
```

Here I used the unary `+` operator to make it a Number instead of a String.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for helping me put it together.

Comment: +1 for using the base 10 on the parseInt, I have seen so many usages of this function resulting unpredictable parsing